# Что значит эта ошибка

Tags: python

Нужно решить задачу, вот условие:
3 6 (целые числа N и M через пробел)
Далее N строк, на каждой из которых одно целое число
4
4
4
Результат:
2
я написал ко и проверил в своем компиляторе, все работает, ввожу код на сайт для теста - выдает ошибку:

```
null
Memory: 3016 
StdErr: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script.py", line 2, in <module>
  N, M = int(input()), int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3 6'
Status: Runtime Error (NZEC)
Статус: Ошибка во время выполнения**
```

что это значит?

вот сам код:

```
import math
N, M = int(input()), int(input())
result, a  = 0, 0
d = []
for i in range(N):
    if N < M:
        a += int(input())
        result = math.ceil(a/M)
    if N == M:
        d.append(int(input()))
        result = max(d)
print(result)
```

Comment: вы вводите в терминал `3 6`, а по факту ваш код предполагает ввод построчно, то есть сначала `3`->`Enter`->`6`->`Enter`

Comment: По вашему заданию, полагаю, олимпиадному, предполагается ввод значений через пробел, в таком случае вам нужна команда `split`

Comment: а именно `inp = input('').split(' ')` и далее
`N, M = int(inp[0]),int(inp[1])`

Comment: `n, m = map(int, input().split())` - классика построчного ввода в Питоне.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправил ваш код с учётом того, что предпологается ввод первых двух значений через пробел, просто используем `split`.

```
import math

inp = input('').split(' ')
N, M = int(inp[0]),int(inp[1])
result, a  = 0, 0
d = []
for i in range(N):
    if N < M:
        a += int(input())
        result = math.ceil(a/M)
    if N == M:
        d.append(int(input()))
        result = max(d)
print(result)
```

Ввод и вывод в терминале:

```
3 6
4
4
4
2
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, я с этим впервые столкнулся...с таким вводом..

Comment: @Сергей Если мой ответ помог вам, пометьте его как "принятый", используя галочку слева -> https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer